# May I use Multi-Release JAR Files in exploded mode?

Tags: java, jar, java-9, java-platform-module-system

So far I saw that [MR Jars](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/238) (as names says) should be... Jar files :)

During my development, I don't want to pack jars every time when I want to run the code (e.g. to run the tests). For me, everything is in the right position except it is all exploded: classes for java9 are in resources and manifest enables MR jars as well.

However, when I run the tests on Java9, the new, java9 classes are not loaded.

While I am still trying to figure if it is some my local issue, it would be helpful to know if for some reason Java9 expects to have MR Jars in a jar file.

EDIT

Example: during the development, whatever I put in the `resources` folder (assuming common Maven structure), it is available when I run tests: either from the IDE or from gradle. What is not working for me is that when I put Java9 classes in the expected location in the resources, neither IDE or gradle "sees" them (of course, I use Java9 vm to run the tests).

[image: example]

Comment: The only place that I am aware of where you can have both the implementations packaged is a jar. How with an exploded release do you wish to resolve to different classes?

Comment: @nullpointer sorry, not sure if I follow. exploded release == jar, except it is not packed. Hence, just follow the same structure.

Comment: My concern being, how do you execute the tests in such case?

Comment: @nullpointer see the edit. I am running tests from the IDE and gradle.

Comment: There is no support for "exploded" MR JARs.

Comment: @AlanBateman but... how am I suppose to test :((( i need to force jar creation before the test and use that jar; and that is such pita.

Comment: Well, I was about to suggest that the question should ideally be how does one test the MRJAR source files?

Comment: @nullpointer well, that is just one use case. I used it here as it is easy to understand. Another example may be Tomcat WAR that is being exploded, it may contain exploded classes in WEB-INF/classes. If you don't mind, I would stick with this title.

Comment: @AlanBateman Is there any existing mailing list discussions around this already or shall one be brought up if you also believe its important?

Comment: @nullpointer - not to my knowledge. While it might be looks useful for testing it has huge implications that were way outside the scope of JEP 238.

Comment: @AlanBateman This _must_ work for testing, as testing is a must. I really don't see the huge implications you mentioned. For me, the jar file is just a container of files. Using Jars should absolutely equal to using an exploded folder with the very same structure. This was always a case with Java. Don't change that.

Comment: @igr - there has always been differences between an exploded tree of classes vs. JAR file. For starters, META-INF/MANIFEST.MF is only meaningful in a JAR file. The manifest is needed to indicate that a JAR file is a MR JAR for example. The summary, is that you can't test a MR JAR without creating a JAR file.

Comment: @AlanBateman got it. Anyhow: how about to make MRJARs working in exploded mode? All I see about MRJArs is that a classloader is reading class files from a different location; this should work the same if the class file is in the jar, or on the classpath (exploded)... Don't get me wrong, but running code without being forced to make an artifact first is really important.